# Maven Junit5 Security Vulnerabilities

Tags: maven, security, junit5

5.4 version of junit5 (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.wcm/io.wcm.testing.aem-mock.junit5/5.4.0) which is currently latest version has internal dependency to io.wcm.testing.aem-mock.core version 5.4.0 (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.wcm/io.wcm.testing.aem-mock.core/5.4.0) which has many vulnerabilities including https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2022-47937.

Does anyone know how can replace org.apache.sling.commons.json for junit5 dependency with https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.sling/org.apache.sling.commons.johnzon. Is it even possible?